# How to make a function to execute n number of times in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def sum_of_squares_of_digits(a):
    a = input("Enter the rpm ")
    s = sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(a))
    print s
    m = s * 323
    print m
    r = a%10
    e = a/10
    x = e%10
    u = int(str(r) + str(e))
    f = u%10
    h = u/10
    l = h%10
    t = int(str(l) + str(f))
    result = m+t
    print u
    print t
    print result

sum_of_squares_of_digits(2)
```

In the above code i need to take the value of "result" and make it as a input to "a" and execute for 10 times.

Comment: In the above code i need to take the value of "result" and make it as a input to "a" and execute for 10 times.

Comment: Have you heard about loops?

Comment: Please put your question in the question and not the comments. And tell us what you tried to do, and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` the variable `result` from your function first:

```
def sum_of_squares_of_digits(a):
    ...
    return result
```

And then you can call the function and use a [`for` loop](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) to execute it 10 times:

```
res = sum_of_squares_of_digits(2) # first call with 2 like in your program
for i in range(10):
    res = sum_of_squares_of_digits(res) # next 10 calls with the returned value
```